# How to delete by attribute from shapefile in SAGA command

Tags: saga

I have lot of shapefiles to erase polygons with same attribute form them. It is usually an easy task when do manually, but how can I use SAGA-GIS command?
Any help?

Comment: Is each saga_cmd an independent command? How can I join these two commands in one script? How to save modified shapefile? Can you write example? I cant't deal with that task:(

Answer (score 1):

Not a SAGA-GIS user but looking at the [Module List](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_module_doc/2.1.3/a2z.html), my guess would be to:

1. [Select your polygons by attribute](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_module_doc/2.1.3/shapes_tools_4.html)

   ```
   saga_cmd shapes_tools 4 -INPUT [-FIELD ] [-EXPRESSION ] [-CASE ] [-COMPARE]
   ```
2. [Delete selection from shapes layer](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_module_doc/2.1.3/shapes_tools_7.html)

   ```
   saga_cmd shapes_tools 7 -INPUT
   ```